# cannot import matplotlib in jupyter

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I have scoured the internet for a concise answer to this question but cant seem to find one. I am using jupyter for python 2 and am trying to import matplotlib.pyplot to no avail. 
This is the code I am running:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

And the error message I receive is:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-385145dcc870> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')

/Users/mbhall88/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>()
    120 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    121 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 122 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label
    123 from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
    124 from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,

/Users/mbhall88/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py in <module>()
     31 from weakref import ref, WeakKeyDictionary
     32 
---> 33 import numpy as np
     34 import numpy.ma as ma
     35 

/Users/mbhall88/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
    183         return loader(*packages, **options)
    184 
--> 185     from . import add_newdocs
    186     __all__ = ['add_newdocs',
    187                'ModuleDeprecationWarning',

/Users/mbhall88/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15 ###############################################################################

/Users/mbhall88/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>()
     15 from .ufunclike import *
     16 
---> 17 from . import scimath as emath
     18 from .polynomial import *
     19 #import convertcode

ImportError: cannot import name scimath
```

I have update matplotlib, numpy, scimath, scipy, and anaconda navigator (basically updated everything I could think of) and restarted everything and I still get this error.

Apologies if this is something simple I have missed but I am not very capable of deciphering some of these error messages.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 'cause the numpy from your Enthought canopy distribution is conflicting with the numpy in your anaconda env and matplotlib was likely built against the enthought numpy but is running against the conda one (or vice versa...)

The easiest fix is uninstall enthought (or conda) and only use one. The harder/messier  fix is to kick the enthought python off your sys.path & PythonPath if it exists.

Comment: Thank you very much. This had been annoying me for quite a few months.